# boost iostream problem

Tags: c++, boost, boost-iostreams

I'm trying to decompress a gzip'd string inside boost using the following code

```
std::string DecompressString(const std::string &compressedString)
{
    std::stringstream src(compressedString);
    if (src.good())
    {
    boost::iostreams::filtering_streambuf<boost::iostreams::input> in(src);
    std::stringstream dst;
    boost::iostreams::filtering_streambuf<boost::iostreams::output> out(dst);
    in.push(boost::iostreams::zlib_decompressor());

    boost::iostreams::copy(in, out);
    return dst.str();
    }
    return "";

}
```

however, whenever I make a call to this functions (such as below)

```
string result = DecompressString("H4sIA");
string result = DecompressString("H4sIAAAAAAAAAO2YMQ6DMAxFfZnCXOgK9AA9ACsURuj9N2wpkSIDootxhv+lN2V5sqLIP0T55cEUgdLR48lUgToTjw/5zaRhBuVSKO5yE5c2kDp5zunIaWG6mz3SxLvjeX/hAQ94wAMe8IAHPCwyMS9mdvYYmTfzdfSQ/rQGjx/t92A578l+T057y1Ff6NW51Uy0h+zkLZ33ByuPtB8IuhdcnSMIglgm/r15/rtJctlf4puMt/i/bN16EotQFgAA");
```

the program will always fail on this line

```
in.push(boost::iostreams::zlib_decompressor());
```

and generate the following exception

```
Unhandled exception at 0x7627b727 in KHMP.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: 
boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<std::logic_error> > at memory location 0x004dd868..
```

I really have no idea on this one... anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Following a suggestion, I switch the code to

```
 boost::iostreams::filtering_streambuf<boost::iostreams::input> in;//(src);

    in.push(boost::iostreams::zlib_decompressor());
    in.push(src);
     std::stringstream dst;
    boost::iostreams::filtering_streambuf<boost::iostreams::output> out;//(dst);
    out.push(dst);
    boost::iostreams::copy(in, out);
```

however, the exception still happens, except it now happens on copy

Answer (score 2):

After following brado86's advice, change `zlib_decompressor()` to `gzip_decompressor()`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are pushing your filters in the wrong order for in.

From what I can understand from the Boost.Iostreams documentations, for input, data flows through the filters in the reverse order in which you've pushed the filters in. So if you change the following lines as follows, I think it should work.

Change

```
boost::iostreams::filtering_streambuf<boost::iostreams::input> in(src);
std::stringstream dst;
boost::iostreams::filtering_streambuf<boost::iostreams::output> out(dst);
in.push(boost::iostreams::zlib_decompressor());
```

to

```
boost::iostreams::filtering_streambuf<boost::iostreams::input> in;
in.push(boost::iostreams::zlib_decompressor());
in.push(src);        // Note the order of pushing filters into the instream.
std::stringstream dst;
boost::iostreams::filtering_streambuf<boost::iostreams::output> out(dst);
```

For more info, read [Boost.Iostreams Documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html).